# CSS-Fixed div with Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, data-visualization

I would like to set my canvas fixed while I'm scrolling the page to the horizontal direction.

However, 
once I set my canvas fixed whole page doesn't move.
And the page starts to move once I un-set my canvas 'fixed'position.

Is there a way to set my canvas fixed while I'm scrolling the page horizontally?

my html and css are as below.
-HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Bhaina+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class='title'>
Story of Everything
    </div>
<div class='canvas'>
    <div class='scroller'>

        <div class='start'></div>
        <div class='start'></div>
        <div class='start'></div>

    </div>

</div>



    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./style.css'>
    <script src='./main.js'></script>

</html>
```

-CSS

```
body{
        margin:0;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden; 
        background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.938)
}

.canvas{
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    margin:none;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;


}
.scroller{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:5%;
    position:relative;
}
.start{
    width:500%;
    height:100%;
}

.title{
    background-color: none;
    top:10%;
    position:fixed inline;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2', cursive;
    font-size:30px;
    color:rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.9);
}
```

For the full code i'm working on, 
here is the fiddle link.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/vYNJxwd

P.S
Since I'm going to make animation depending on the horizontal scroll position using 
scrollmagic, I think this is the fist step for my project. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I found out! It was because my canvas is having Scrollers inside of it. I'm going to keep this posting and leave a link for someone who needs help for future